# Why isn't the install banner showing in my PWA hosted on GitHub Pages?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, github-pages, service-worker, manifest.json

When i host the PWA on localhost, the banner shows. It's the exact same code i have hosted [here](https://stringmanolo.github.io/PWASoundRecord/)

The github [repository](https://github.com/StringManolo/PWASoundRecord) is available as well.

If you go to the settings button, the install application option appears. But the banner doesn't.

I tried replacing the manifest.json with a manifest.webmanifest as i saw in a PWA working template hosted on GitHub Pages.